# lodash map data only if array exists

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a small function I need to write that takes the values of two objects and stores them into an array which I then merge together for a single array of data.

The issue is that there one of the arrays may not exist so it should just returned an empty array so that the merge wouldn't complain.

```
let active = _.map(this.modalData.currentExceptions.activeExceptions.active, 'QID');
let future = _.map(this.modalData.currentExceptions.futureExceptions.future, 'QID')
let combined = _.merge(active, future);
```

In this case, `futureExceptions` isnt an array in this data set so map throws an `undefiend` error.

Is there something I can add to this `.map` will return an empty array if the key / object isn't found?

Comment: What do the objects look like? What's 'QID'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/#get). It allows you to set a default when a key  resolves to `undefined`.

```
let active = _.map(
  _.get(
    this.modalData.currentExceptions.activeExceptions, 'active', []
  ), 
  'QID'
);

let future = _.map(
  _.get(
    this.modalData.currentExceptions.futureExceptions, 'future', []
  ),
  'QID'
)

let combined = _.merge(active, future);
```